BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME not updating in code after modifying build.gradle and syncing project
I'm experiencing an issue with BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME in my code. When I change the version name in the build.gradle file and sync the project, the change isn't reflected in my code. Instead, the code continues to display the previous version name until I either rebuild the entire project or make some change to the project code.
I've checked the generated BuildConfig class, and it shows the new version name correctly. However, when I log the BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME value, it still shows the old one.
Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?
Also, I have recently updated the targetSdk to 34, gradle version to 8.4 and kotlin version to 2.0

did you find why this is happening?

Also encountering this very annoying issue. were you able to fix this?

@Gabrielle It's happening because of the new Kotlin version - 2.0.0 in my case.

@YellowJ I haven't found any better solutions other than downgrading the Kotlin version to 1.9.24.

I solved this by disabling incremental compilation .
In your project's gradle.properties file, add kotlin.incremental=false.
Now, when I edit the version name, it's reflected in the next app build/launch.
